# Как выровнять тег A по центру Li?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делал резиновое меню, все получилось,но не могу опустить пункты меню на середину. Пробовал `vertical-align`, `text-align` и ничего не работает.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    display:block;
}
body{
   background:#444;
}
header {
    height:7%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.right{
float:left;
    background-color: #000;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    }
.menu{float:left;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
width:70%;
height:100%;
 }
.left{float:left;
    background-color: #000;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;

}
img{width:10%;
Height:100%;
background-color:#000;
}
ul{margin-left:10%;
width:80%;
height:100%;
background-color:#cee2d3}
li{
width:10%;
height:100%;
background-color:#669900}
a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;}
```

1
2

4
3

Comment: Вы бы хоть скриншот приложили ... Совсем ведь не понятно чего вы хотите. Или приложите код HTML & CSS

Comment: Прошу прощения, уже добавил

Comment: т.е. вам нужно вертикально отцентрировать цифры в блоке?
http://codepen.io/astor/pen/dXxBrQ

Comment: Да, благодаря вашим настройкам, все получилось, жаль line-height не  отцентровывает в процентах, а не пикселях. Большое спасибо, за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчный элемент внутри блочного можно выравнять вертикально, если задать блочному  элементу твердую высоту, например: height: 30px; и line-height: 30px;

Конечно же это только один из множества вариантов вертикального центрирования)).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 30px; /* устанавливаем постоянную высоту */
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #669900;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px; /* устанавливаем line-height равный высоте элемента */
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```